# gtkmm how to use header bar instead of titlebar if I'm not using .ui file

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I wanna replace Notebook bar with Gtk::HeaderBar in one of my projects, and since I'm not using .ui file, but I'm directly programming everything I wonder how can I hide title bar and use header bar.

Comment: Gtk::NoteBook and Gtk::HeaderBar are very different widgets and are not equivalent to each other. Rewriting your question see [ask] would help us understand what you need and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks, you are a life saver I've solved it simply by adding header bar to the vertical box.

Comment: ok, better yet void Gtk::Window::set_titlebar  (Widget& titlebar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we need to create new header bar which will replace our titlebar and then simply providing window.set_titlebar() with Gtk::Header widget solved it.

Definition:

```
void Gtk::Window::set_titlebar  (Widget& titlebar)
```